# Zapier: unable to get raw response

Tags: node.js, zapier

I'm calling a Google Photos API endpoint which returns a plain/text with an ID.

```js
const http = require('https'); // require('http') if your URL is not https

const makeDownloadStream = (url) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.request(url, resolve).on('error', reject).end();
  });

const perform = async (z, bundle) => {
  const stream = await makeDownloadStream(bundle.inputData.file, z);

  z.console.log("Yeah let's do it");

  const response = await z.request({
    url: 'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads',
    method: 'POST',
    body: stream,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${bundle.authData.access_token}`,
      "Content-type": "application/octet-stream",
      "X-Goog-Upload-Protocol": "raw",
      "X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type": bundle.inputData.X_Goog_Upload_Content_Type,
    }
  });

  z.console.log("I'm already dead before coming here");

  //const text = await response.text();  
  return {
    "upload_token": "test"
  };
};


module.exports = {
  operation: {
    perform: perform,
    inputFields: [
      {
        key: 'X_Goog_Upload_Content_Type',
        label: 'Upload-Content-Type',
        type: 'string',
        required: false,
        list: false,
        altersDynamicFields: false,
      },
      { key: 'file', required: true, type: 'file', label: 'File' },
    ],
  },
  key: 'upload_bytes',
  noun: 'Upload',
  display: {
    label: 'Uploading bytes',
    description:
      "Upload the raw bytes to a Google Server. This doesn't result in any media items being created in the user’s Google Photos account. Instead, it returns an upload token which identifies the uploaded bytes.",
    hidden: false,
    important: true,
  },
};
```

This request fails with the following stacktrace:

```
== Log
Unhandled error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
What happened:
  Starting POST request to https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads
  Received 200 code from https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads after 193ms
  Received content "redacted"
  Converting circular structure to JSON
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at sendLog (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/zapier-platform-core/src/tools/create-logger.js:166:16)
    at logResponse (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/zapier-platform-core/src/http-middlewares/after/log-response.js:71:10)
    at Object.collector.then.newOutput (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/zapier-platform-core/src/middleware.js:80:37)
    at bound (domain.js:402:14)
    at Object.runBound (domain.js:415:12)
    at Object.tryCatcher (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (:censored:9:d1ba0cf2aa:/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
```

It seems the automatic http logger is trying to parse the response although it is not valid JSON data.

I tried using `raw: true` with z.request in order to circumvent the logger but still same problem.

Is there a way to prevent Zapier logger to fail?

Comment: What's the response from API?

Comment: The Google API sent a 200 code, is it what you are asking?

Comment: I mean the response bidy

Comment: The response body is a upload token which is in the form of a raw text string, in text/plain. Something like: AEnB2UqT6y8KyZNCPyAaFeCj7I_ABIlwLJQMpltYzQ7D8blW4v3uKSlMT7dbNjFV0i_7ApzoR-i26ZtZ9kHkB7bI8n8ojgOnNA

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the Zapier core library (of which I am a maintainer). I've filed it as https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/issues/302. If you've got more info to fill in re: the structure of the response, that would be helpful! Feel free to comment on the Github issue.